# Finish an especific user's session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

At this time I want to put a button in the user's list "Disconnect" to finish the session when I need it

I'm using sorcery authentication

I added a new route in "routes.rb"

```
get "killsession"    => "users#killsession",  :as => "killsession"
```

I also Have a method in the "users_controller.rb"

```
def killsession
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

And in the view in the file "index.html.erb" I have it

```
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= image_tag "#{user.definir_status_icono}" %></td>
            <td><%= user.id %></td>
            <td><%= user.username.capitalize %></td>
            <td><%= user.name %></td>
            <td><%= user.last_login_at.strftime("%l:%M %p, %B %d, %Y") rescue nil %></td>
            <td>
                <%= user.last_logout_at.strftime("%l:%M %p, %B %d, %Y") rescue nil %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= link_to "Ver Mas", edit_user_path(user), 
                    :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %>

                <%= link_to 'Eliminar', user_path(user), 
                    :confirm    => "Esta seguro ?", 
                    :method     => :delete,
                    :remote     => true,
                    :class      => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>

                <% if user.online == 1 %>
                    <%= link_to "Disconnect", killsession_path(user), 
                        :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-warning' %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to "Disconnect", '', 
                        :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-warning',
                        :disabled => true %>
                <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

I don't know how to do that button because when I clicked the button just finish the current session, and doesn't finish the especific user's session

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session hash is local to, well, your session. Read about it [here](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210255#user-cookies). So when you modify it, it affects no one else. This approach won't work.

Generally, you don't have direct access to other users' session data. If you use cookie store (default!), it is stored locally in their browser. If you used for example ActiveRecordStore, you could possibly tamper with database table directly. But I would strongly discourage it - for security reasons as well as possibility to change session store easily.

So now, you want to sign out another user - any authentication library should allow it. If you use devise, it's as simple as `sign_out user`. If you wrote your own authentication module, you should know how to destroy a session (maybe resetting user's session token in users table?)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just follow [this ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery) and log the user out?  This seems simpler than actually trying to destroy a user's session manually.

Comment: I did the complete Ascii cast, and everything works ok, this is just another function that i need to put on the index.html.erb to disconnect an user with a button when i want

Comment: Right, and what I'm saying is that button would make a call to the logout path for whichever user is in question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your routes are wrong ? Destroy a session is a DELETE not a GET and you set a params in your index.html.erb using killsession_path(user)

```
# The :as is useless
delete "/killsession/:id_of_selected_user" => "users#killsession"
```

and your button have to be like that :

```
<%= button_to 'Logout', killsession_path(:id_of_selected_user => user.id), :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: I did it like you told me, but happens the same, it just finish the current user session, and I just need to finish the session of an especific user, not the current